# jaxb unmarshalling giving NULL to anytype element in xsd

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I am getting NULL value eventhough there is some value in xml using jaxb unmarshalling.

Element in xsd

```
<xs:element name="Account" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
```

does not have type attribute.

In its respective Java class AccountNo become java.lang.Object type.

but after Unmarshalling xml

```
<AccountNo>GDF23232223</AccountNo>
```

output comes [AccountNo=NULL]

My unmarshalling code

```
 jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("net.process");
   Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
   document = (Document) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputFile);
```

can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Is the element with no type specified a root element, or an element nested in your document?

Comment: it is nested element in docment, Not a root element.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem. Try to get the value using
   element.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()

There I got the correct value